# How to get the expected time complexity of while loop?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, randomized-algorithms

How to get the expected time complexity of while loop below?

```
While infinity:
  case1: Return 0 with a probability of p(1 - p)
  case2: Return 1 with a probability of p(1 - p)
  case3: otherwise repeat this loop until return 0 or 1
```

I can understand the probability that this loop runs only one time is $2p(1 - p)$. But I cannot understand how much the expected run time of this is. Can anyone let me know it and why?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric random variables?

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the probability that the `while` loop runs **exactly** $k$ times, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then the expected number of loops is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}k\times\mathbb{P}(\text{loop runs }k\text{ times})$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $q:=2p(1-p)$ the probability that the while loop halts at a certain point.

The probability the loop runs **exactly** once is $q$
The probability the loop runs **exactly** twice is $(1-q)\cdot q$
The probability the loop runs **exactly** three times is $(1-q)^2 \cdot q$

And you can see where this is going: the probability the loop runs exactly $n$ times is given by: $(1-q)^{n-1}\cdot q$ and as @Yuval Filmus suggested, this is a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

According to wikipedia, the expected value of such a geometric distribution is $\frac{1}{q}$, so the average complexity of your loop is: $\frac{1}{2 p (1-p)}$